# Renaming files without file extensions

Tags: linux, rename

I have a series of files named `KLLxxx` (the `x` represents numbers). They're text files but have no file extension to them. Just files that say `KLL` followed by three digits. I want them all to end with the file extension `.fastq`. Such as `KLL123` -> `KLL123.fastq`.

So I tried using this command

```
mv KLL* KLL*.fastq
```

But I keep on getting the error message:

```
mv: target 'KLL067.fastq' is not a directory
```

I know about the rename command function, but I've never used Perl before so I don't know how to approach this. I know this is a basic question, but this is my first time trying out Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the following `find` command in the directory you are looking at will do the trick:

```
find . -name 'KLL[0-9][0-9][0-9]' -exec sh -c 'mv $0 $0.fastq' {} \;
```

Which will add the extension `.fastq` to any file name starting with `KLL` followed by three digits.

Comment: There's no need for the sh invocation: "-exec mv {} {}.fastq" by itself works and doesn't spin up a whole new shell for each file. And, of course, weird things will happen if any of the KLL files have "weird" characters in their names (eg., spaces, tabs, slashes).

Comment: ... just something for the OP to keep in mind when their requirement changes next week is all.

Answer (score 6):

`prename`... rename with Perl expressions. The following command takes the list of files (KLL*), and for each one, it grabs the entire name of KLL plus three numbers (`KLL\d{3})`) and saves that into the special named `$1` variable. the `s` at the beginning of the expression means 'substitute' what's between the first two `//` with what is between the 2nd set, which is the full filename in `$1` and append `.fastq` to it.

```
prename 's/(KLL\d{3})/$1.fastq/' KLL*
```

Comment: Use `'s/(KLL\d{3})$/$1.fastq/'`  - otherwise it will rename KLL* files that have already been renamed, or with extra chars after the 3 digits.

Answer (score 2):

many possible solutions here, this should be one:

```
for f in KLL*; do mv "$f" "$f.fastq"; done
```

Comment: for f in KLL[0-9][0-9][0-9]